# Image Compression in ASP .Net Core without reducing the image quality

Tags: asp.net-core

Best ways to perform Image Compression in ASP .Net Core to store in server and return the original image to client without reducing the image quality

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms404280(v=vs.100)) library to compress the uploaded files when you store them on disk, then decompress them when you stream them back.  That library should be available in .NET Core 2.0